# TideSDK - adding options to installation

Tags: installation, tidesdk

I need to get the user to set some options upon installation. The options set would then need to be available to read from within the app.

The options would be some simple key/values, in plain text form.

Is there any way to do this with TideSDK?

Answer (score 0):

can you elaborate how exactly you want user to input the key value pairs from the installer / while installing ?

The current installer does not provide any kind of functionality to set variables like that however you can easily do that using the sqlite database available builtin within TideSDK / webkit.

you can detect the first running of the application by setting the flag in the database.. and ask user to input the parameters (key/value) you want him to add and store it.